# How to change the python editor spyder workspace in an easy and fast way?

Tags: spyder

In order to work with projects on different locations of the filesystem, we need an easy/fast way to change the workspace.

Is there any such way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. From the menu open View->Panes->Project Explorer
2. Click to the folder icon on the right-top corner of the Project Explorer.
3. Select your new workspace.

Learned from http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.scientific.spyder/3111